# ¿Qué es una instancia en POO?

Tags: java, poo

Llevo tiempo con la programación y siempre que leo u oigo las palabras **instancia** o **instanciamos** me doy una idea de lo que se está hablando pero no estoy seguro del todo.

Yo entiendo que la **instancia** de un objeto es cuando creamos un nuevo objeto y le reservamos un espacio en la memoria:

```
Object obj = new Object();
```

¿Estoy en lo cierto? ¿Olvidé algo? ¿Hay alguna pieza de información que me falte?

Comment: Es correcto, y a partir de entonces ese objeto dispondrá de todos los métodos de su clase. Esto es así para java y para los demás lenguajes POO

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En Programación Orientada a Objetos o POO hay que distinguir dos conceptos diferentes:

- **clase**: Una clase es un prototipo o molde que indica qué características van a tener y cómo se van a comportar los elementos creados a partir de dicha clase.
- **objeto**: Los objetos son los elementos creados a partir de las clases antes mencionadas. En algunos contextos o lenguajes se suele usar también el término *instancia*

Es decir, a partir de una clase se pueden crear infinitos objetos o instancias.

Fíjate que las definiciones anteriores no indican dónde o cómo se ha de crear el objeto o la instancia y es que ese es un aspecto irrelevante en este caso. En lenguajes como C++, por ejemplo, tienes la capacidad de elegir si el objeto se va a crear en la memoria dinámica (heap) o en la pila del programa (stack):

```
class POO
{
  // ...
};

int main()
{
  POO a; // a se crea en el stack
  POO* b = new POO; // b se crea en el heap.

  delete b; // La memoria dinámica es necesario liberarla.
}
```

Sin embargo esto no tiene por qué ser así en todos los lenguajes ya que cada uno tiene sus propias características y la teoría de la programación orientada a objetos es independiente del lenguaje utilizado.

Comment: Buen creo que ya entendi, Una clase es un molde que indica las propiedades, formas de comportarse de un objeto o instancia(sinónimo de objeto):  Automovil **auto** = new Automovil(); donde Instanciamos  la clase Automovil en el objeto auto. sigo creyendo que instanciar algo como asignar clase.

Comment: Si fuese _asignar clase_ se podría entender que posteriormente se puede hacer una asignación diferente (otra clase, sin herencia entre ellas) y no es verdad. Que algunos lenguajes soporten eso no implica que esté relacionado con la teoría de la POO.

Comment: Bueno eso pensé en el area de Java, llevo tiempo con esa duda.

Comment: A mi entender, debería aclararse que el concepto de clase sólo existe en los lenguajes orientados a objetos de clasificación. En los que se usa prototipación  (ej: [Self](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_(programming_language)) dicho concepto no existe, la reutilización de código se realiza de otra manera.

Answer (score 5):

La instancia de una clase, es el objeto el cual a partir del momento de su existencia; es capaz de acceder a:

- Métodos
- Propiedades

Dependiendo del modificador de acceso que estos posean

- **`public`**
- **`private`**
- **`protected`**
- [*Aunque noto que otros lenguajes tienen una lista un tanto mas extensa*](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)

Recordemos también que la instancia nos da la posibilidad de asignar valores que la clase pudiera estar esperando para recibir y manipular por medio de su método constructor interno.

Recurrimos a este proceso por que el tener una clase así:

```
class Algo 
{
 /*algunos valores y propiedades*/
}
```

Tan solo representa:

- El [*blueprint*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blueprint_(dibujo_t%C3%A9cnico)) de una entidad
- Los posibles métodos que han de manipular a las propiedades para devolver en concecuencia en un resultado esperado

Pero por decirlo de algún modo, la clase ahí no *es capaz* de hablar y mostrar el resultado de su contenido; no al menos hasta que el objeto que la representa recibe posibles valores para su método constructor y en concencuencia puede acceder a las acciones o verbos que esta contiene.

Sin embargo para tener un objeto que represente a la clase no es estrictamente necesario hacer uso de la instancia; no al menos con la estrtuctura común.

Podemos hacer uso de `static factory method`, como no soy diestro en Java entonces te dejo un ejemplo en PHP pero que igualmente debe darte una idea de como:

- Dentro de la clase llevamos a cabo la instancia de la misma
- Convertimos en `protected` al método constructor
- Al método que reciba los eventuales valores que espera la clase lo convertimos en `static` para no depender diractamente de la instancia por fuera de la clase así:

código de ejemplo:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

class Demo
{
    /**
     * @var $value 
    */
    protected function __construct(protected int $value)
    {}

    /**
     * 
     * recibe como parámetro un valor numérico entero
     * retorna una nueva instancia de la clase Demo
     * 
     * @param int $value
     * @return new Demo object class
    */
    public static function showValue(int $value): object
    {
        return new Demo($value);
    }
}

var_dump(Demo::showValue(123));
```

Que nos da la siguiente salida:

```
object(Demo)#1 (1) {
  ["value":protected]=>
  int(123)
}
```

> Como se puede observar aunque el método es estático y este no esta bajo el contexto de un objeto, lo que este nos retorna si es un objeto referenciando a la clase declarada así mismo identificando su propiedad, el tipo, modificador de acceso y si esta o no inicializada.

Observa el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

class Demo
{

    /**
     * 
     * retorna una nueva instancia de la clase Demo
     * 
     * @return new Demo object class
    */
    public static function showInstance(): object
    {
        return new Demo();
    }
}

var_dump(Demo::showInstance());

var_dump(new Demo());
```

En ambos casos observamos como resultado lo siguiente:

```
object(Demo)#1 (0) {
}
object(Demo)#1 (0) {
}
```

En ambos casos observamos que obtenemos un objeto instanciado de la clase *Demo* tanto de la forma *regular* como así mismo por medio del retorno de una instancia dentro de un método estático.

**Lecturas de interés y referencias**

- [Métodos estáticos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php)
- [Static factory method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCJJ7rf087Y)
- [Static factory method in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-constructors-vs-static-factory-methods)

Comment: Veo más cerca tu definición que la respuesta anterior. Creo que todo lo que has escrito, se resume que "la clase es una instancia a un objeto", esta instancia permite trabajar con todas las características dentro de la clase.

Comment: Por añadir a lo que bien dice Aprendiz, un ejemplo de este patrón en Java lo tenemos en la clase `Integer`, en su método `valueOf`. Éste método estático está sobrecargado, y se puede llamar con un valor entero, o con un `String`. Por lo que el método devolverá un nuevo Integer tanto si le pasamos un número, como si le pasamos una cadena que contenga un número. Es decir `Integer.valueOf(5) == Integer.valueOf("5")`. Aquí se puede ver la implementación, que es muy parecida: http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/Integer-source.html

Comment: Muy cierto @ordago de hecho con el tema de Java estuve leyendo al respecto del `static factory......` con el libro Effective Java

Comment: La clase es la definición del tipo de dato (que métodos y variables tiene) y la instancia es el valor de ese tipo?